# Javascript push to elements in a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I need to produce an array formatted as :

```
products : 
[
    {
        "product_id": 32,
        "quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "product_id": 33,
        "quantity": 2,
        "product_options": 
        [
            {
                "id": 87,
                "value": 10
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I can do the product_id & quantity ok using :

```
productID = 32;
prodQuantity = 2;
var row2 = {};
row2.product_id = productID;
row2.quantity = prodQuantity;
product.push(row2);

productID = 33;
prodQuantity = 2;
var row2 = {};
row2.product_id = productID;
row2.quantity = prodQuantity;
product.push(row2);
```

How do I add the element product_options with the id & value.

I have tried variations of:

```
var row3 = {};
row3.id = 87;
row3.value = 10;    
cartArray['product_options'].push(row3);
```

I managed it using:

```
var prodQuantity = app.getValue('popupDropdown').value;
var cartArray = [];
var optionID = app.getValue('popupDropdown4').value;
var row2 = {};
var row3 = {};
var row4 = {};
var tempArray = [];
row2.product_id = productID;
row2.quantity = prodQuantity;
cartArray.push(row2);
row3.id = optionID;
row3.value = Rule4Value;
tempArray.push(row3);
row4.product_options = tempArray;
cartArray.push(row4);
```

But I see the answer below is much simpler.

Comment: No mention that the OP is using jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `product_options` of `row2` like this:

```
row2.product_options = [
    {
        id: 87,
        value: 10
    }
];
```

To explain:

`product_options` is a key in `row2`. It's value is an array with a single element that is an object with the keys `id` and `value`.